# Button does nothing on click in C++ Builder 10.2

Tags: c++builder

I'm trying to make Button change Label. When I run project and press button it does nothing.
Here is code for the button:

```
void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)

{
    Label1->Text =  "Hello" + Edit1->Text + " !";
}
```

Here is my View:
[image]

Comment: Did you set the OnClick event for the button to that function? You can for instance do that on the Events tab in the Object Inspector. If that link is not made, the button won't know what to do, when it is clicked.

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis you're right, thanks. Mobile Tutorial (PDF) seems to be underdeveloped: there is no word about that, thought it covers basic stuff.

Comment: I guess it is so obvious for someone having used Delphi or C++Builder for a long time, like the author, that they simply forgot to mention it. <g>

Comment: @Rudy Velthuis It seems those author is really absent-minded: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53408069/7518118

Comment: I don't currently have a Mac (in repair), so I can't follow such tutorials anyway. I don't know if that is absent-mindedness or simply some things the author assumes to be well known. I can't check it. I do know that of all the tutorials I have seen in my life,  hardly any was exactly as portrayed, due to differences in system, hardware, software, etc.